# HttpPostedFile and SaveAs not saving a part of the path

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to save a file that is uploaded using an HttpPostedFile control.

The main issue I'm running into, is that it won't create a new folder for the file.

In the code below, "file" is an HttpPostedFile.

So I have my base path that I define like this:

```
    Dim basePath = "D:\\game\\world\\map\\MediaFiles\\"
```

Then I get the file name like this:

```
    Dim fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)
```

Now I want to create a new path like this using the gameId (guid):

```
    Dim newFolderAndFile As String = gameId + fileName
```

And then combine the path with the base path and save:

```
    Dim saveAsPath = Path.Combine(basePath, newFolderAndFile)

    file.SaveAs(saveAsPath)
```

But when I try that, I always get an error like this:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path
>   'D:\game\world\map\MediaFiles\05a10e9c-e8a9-49ed-ad4f-34b6b4650ef3\5.jpg'

So it looks like the **saveAsPath** is being constructed correctly, however **SaveAs** isn't saving it.

How can I get SaveAs to create the path and file?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you'll have to create your folder with [Directory.​Create​Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2). Also, you still need to do some check because it`s possible that your program does not have access to the path and the same error could happen.

Comment: Are you missing backslash between gameId + fileName?

Answer (score 2):

As the_lotus explained, you need to create the directory first before saving the file

```
Dim basePath = "D:\game\world\map\MediaFiles\"
Dim fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)

' make new folder
system.io.direcotry.createdirectory(basepath & gameid)

Dim saveAsPath = (basePath & gameid & "\" & filename)
file.SaveAs(saveAsPath)
```

I'm not sure about the double slashes, I think that's not needed...